# Multi text should change together on hover state

Tags: html, css

There are `<a>` tag and `<span>` tag, both should be change together on hover.
right now its happening separate.

C

```css
.footer-menu-mob li a:hover,
.footer-menu-mob li span:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row footer-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav footer-menu-mob">
    <li><a href="#">TITLE1<br><span>TEXT1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE2<br><span>TEXT2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE3<br><span>TEXT3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TITLE4<br><span>TEXT4</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can any one suggest me how i can do for together.

Comment: what do you mean both should be change together?

Comment: You probably want to format the `span` differently when the `a` gets hovered ... `a:hover span { … }`

Comment: TITLE1 & TEXT1 - both should be color change together.

Comment: your snippet works fine for me, but I would do as roy says, change the hover for the span to be on the anchor - you probably don't even need to style the span separately (unless it starts off as a different colour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
.footer-menu-mob li a:hover, .footer-menu-mob li a:hover span {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: green;
}
```

Let me know if works